# configuring namecheap domains with heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain, namecheap

I have a app on heroku(paid dyno):

**https://example.herokuapp.com/**

I have purchased a domain:

**www.example.com**

After reading multiple guides I can't figure out how to do the following:

- point domain to my heroku app(with SSL)
- configure a subdomain like **api.example.com**

The overall goal is to have a domain like **api.example.com**

Thanks. *NOTE: Please do not simply link to documents from heroku and namecheap. I have read them all, and they are out of date/unspecific.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have just done something similar recently and I think it's what you need. In my case, I need to turn on SSL ACM ([Automatic Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management)) for my existing heroku app.

First, you need to turn on Automatic Certificate Management to get the SSL certificate from heroku.

- Check if ACM is on

  ```
  $ heroku certs:auto -a [your app name]
  === Automatic Certificate Management is disabled on [your app name]

  Note: if you don't have heroku-toolbelt installed, just ignore this step. It's just a check.
  ```
- Go to heroku dashboard's Settings
- Click on 'Configure SSL' button
- Choose ACM and click continue
- Click 'Add domain' button if api.mysite.com is not already there.
- Take note of the 'DNS Target' which is something like api.mysite.com.herokudns.com
- Check certificate status again

  ```
  $ heroku certs:auto -a [your app name]
  === Automatic Certificate Management is enabled on [your app name]
  ```

Second, you need to login to your namecheap dns zonefile page and add a CNAME.

- Change CNAME to 'api' record to point to api.mysite.com.herokudns.com  (or whatever is there in the DNS Target above)

  ```
  TYPE        NAME        VALUE
  A           @           10.10.10.10                         <<< your www ip 
  CNAME       api         api.mysite.com.herokudns.com        <<< you need this one.
  ```
- Wait 10 mins
- Browse to api.mysite.com

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do. just to clarify, all I had to do was:
- add the domain "api.mysite.com" to my heroku app
- add a cname record in namecheap with host = api, distination = api.mysite.herokudns.com
- enable automatic certificate management
- wait ~10 minutes 

result: https://api.mysite.com

Comment: Note that ACM is not available for the free tier.

Answer (score 6):

Considering your app is at `https://example.herokuapp.com/`, and assuming you own the domain `www.example.com` as stated, follow the following steps to have your app running on your custom domain:

**Using the Heroku CLI**

1. Add a custom domain with a subdomain

`$ heroku domains:add www.example.com`

2. Add a custom root domain

`$ heroku domains:add example.com`

**On namecheap**

After signing into your account

1. Select Domain List from the left side menu and click the **Manage** button next to your domain:

[image]

2. Navigate to the **Advanced DNS** tab and click the **Add New Record** button in the Host Records section:

[image]

3. To use `www.example.com` and `example.com`, the following host records should be created:

**`URL Redirect Record`** for `@` to forward to `http://www.example.com` (`http://www.yourdomain.tld` in the picture)

**`CNAME Record`** for `www` mapped to your Heroku Domain `www.example.com.herokudns.com.` (`www.yourdomain.tld.herokudns.com.` in the picture)

[image]

4. (*Optional*) To use any other subdomain, like `app.example.com` and `example.com`, you should create the following records:

**`URL Redirect Record`** for `@` to forward to `http://app.example.com` (`http://app.yourdomain.tld` in the picture)

**`CNAME Record`** for app mapped to your Heroku Domain `app.example.com.herokudns.com.` (`app.yourdomain.tld.herokudns.com.` in the picture)

[image]

That's it! Now your app should be running at `www.example.com`.

For more information on the namecheap side you can check [this link](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9737/2208/pointing-a-domain-to-the-heroku-app).

Answer (score 4):

So CNAME didn't work for me. In Heroku, I setup my domain as follows:
[image]

Then in Namecheap, I setup a redirect and an ALIAS WWW Record with your Heroku DNS Target

[image]

Trust me if anyone has been struggling with this, try this configuration! Worked for me after many trial and error attempts.

Comment: I was hoping this would work but it didn't I knew I should've stayed with goDaddy