# configuring heroku hobby dyno with a namecheap domain at root level

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, dns, namecheap

This question is highly similar to this, but barely different:
[configuring namecheap domains with heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499677/configuring-namecheap-domains-with-heroku)

Here is what I have (for the purposes of hiding the original site, I have omitted its name for the string 'asdf'):

A namecheap domain titled as follows:  asdf.com

A herokuapp running on a dyno that is hobby level that also has ACM set for automatic certificate management.  It is running at https://asdf.herokuapp.com/ and this link works and gets my pushes from github integration.  It is awesome :)

I want to link these up so that instead of having my site as https://asdf.herokuapp.com it would instead be https://asdf.com, so that is why I went and bought the namecheap domain for it, but linking these together I have failed at every opportunity.  I have tried many different patterns but unfortunately I'm unknowledged on this layer of things.  Here is something I have tried, but does not work:

On Heroku: Create a custom domain of:  asdf.com
Heroku then supplies me with: asdf.com.herokudns.com

I then go into namecheap, and remove any and all possible cnames or redirects.
I create a new CNAME | host: www | target: asdf.com.herokudns.com

When trying to hit the site, I get this error:
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

If I try changing CNAME host to @ on namecheap, I get:
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Any help is greatly appreciated, and if more information is needed just ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing the same issue. I've contacted Namecheap and Heroku both for support. This is what I've come up with, but my domain is still not resolving.

Since you're pointing www.mollydwellness.org at your app, you'll need to make sure you've added that to your Heroku config (currently you only have the non-www version assigned):

```
$ heroku domains:add www.mollydwellness.org --app mollydwellness
```

Once that is added, you should receive a new DNS target that you'll need to use to update your CNAME record.

```
$ heroku domains

=== mollydwellness Heroku Domain
mollydwellness.herokuapp.com

=== mollydwellness Custom Domains
Domain Name             DNS Record Type  DNS Target
──────────────────────  ───────────────  ────────────────────────────────────
www.mollydwellness.org  CNAME            www.mollydwellness.org.herokudns.com
mollydwellness.org      ALIAS or ANAME   mollydwellness.org.herokudns.com
```

Namecheap Config

```
 Type       Host      Value        TTL        
    CNAME Record        www

    www.mollydwellness.org.herokudns.com.

    5 min


    URL Redirect Record 
    @

    http://www.mollydwellness.org/

    Unmasked
```

I am told to give it another 30 minutes before contacting support again. It's been 45 minutes and still not resolving.

Very confused, probably just going to deploy it myself to a VPS because that would be easier at this point. I went with Heroku to save myself time, but it appears there can be no shortcuts. More help from the community would be great.

Comment: Nice to see someone else having same issue as me.  Ultimately though this would be an amazing thing as you could have a live site using your own custom domain that also can accept continuous deployment simultaneously, which was my ultimate goal.  If I have to set up a VPS then there goes continuous deployment :P

Comment: Any luck Sean Kelly?

Comment: Hey yes, I was able to get my domain mounted by making sure the DNS target from heroku domains:add www.mollydwellness.org --app mollydwellness is adding in NameCheap. However heroku was not able to connect CLEARDB to my Adonis JS app, so I ended up moving to digital ocean. It kept adding in sqlite and wouldn't allow me to change to production build under their hobbyist package. pretty annoying

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you need to do for dns, is going to heroku, setting the following on the custom domain :

*.mywebsite.com

mywebsite.com

www.mywebsite.com

on Namecheap you do the following configuration:

CNAME Record    @  myapp.herokuapp.com.   1 min

CNAME Record    www   myapp.herokuapp.com.  1 min

URL Redirect Record  @  https://www.myapp.herokuapp.com Unmasked

URL Redirect Record www https://www.aipredictor.herokuapp.com  Unmasked

and you are done. that covers all of the possible scenarios.